# Hide a column or change the order of columns in a MySQL output

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement i need help with that looks like this

```
SELECT 
  unix_timestamp(prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldValue) AS dato,
  prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId AS var,
  (SELECT prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldValue FROM prefix_rsform_submission_values WHERE prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId = (var -1)) AS lykke
FROM
  prefix_rsform_submissions
  INNER JOIN prefix_rsform_submission_values ON (prefix_rsform_submissions.SubmissionId = prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionId)
WHERE
  prefix_rsform_submissions.FormId = 10 AND 
  prefix_rsform_submissions.UserId = 278 AND 
  prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldName = 'dato'
ORDER BY
  prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId
```

Im using the result in a Joomla module. I need the first column to contain the 'Dato' and the Second column to contain the 'Lykke'
Is there anyway to get rid of the 'var' column from the output or let it come in the 3rd column?
Currently it outputs this and i need dato first and then lykke. It does not matter if var is in the out as long as it is not in the first or second column.

```
dato        var      lykke
1290254400  1393     10
1448020800  1397     9
1637409600  1401     9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order in the select clause of the column. Use this:

```
 SELECT t.dato, t.lykke
  FROM
  (SELECT 
      unix_timestamp(prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldValue) AS dato,
      prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId AS var,
      (SELECT prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldValue FROM prefix_rsform_submission_values WHERE prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId = (var -1)) AS lykke
    FROM
      prefix_rsform_submissions
      INNER JOIN prefix_rsform_submission_values ON (prefix_rsform_submissions.SubmissionId = prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionId)
    WHERE
      prefix_rsform_submissions.FormId = 10 AND 
      prefix_rsform_submissions.UserId = 278 AND 
      prefix_rsform_submission_values.FieldName = 'dato'
    ORDER BY
      prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId) t
```

By this way you can make the same order as you want.

EDITED CODE WITH ALIAS:

```
SELECT t.dato, t.lykke
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      unix_timestamp(pr3.FieldValue) AS dato,
      pr3.SubmissionValueId AS var,
      (SELECT pr1.FieldValue 
          FROM prefix_rsform_submission_values AS pr1
          WHERE pr1.SubmissionValueId = (var -1)) AS lykke
    FROM
      prefix_rsform_submissions AS pr2
      INNER JOIN prefix_rsform_submission_values pr3 ON (pr2.SubmissionId = pr3.SubmissionId)
    WHERE
      pr2.FormId = 10 AND 
      pr2.UserId = 278 AND 
      pr3.FieldName = 'dato'
    ORDER BY
      pr3.SubmissionValueId) AS t
```

Comment: The nested select statement uses the var, So it can not simply be removed

Comment: @user3165012 then use the full name `prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId` instead of the `var` in the nested select statement.

Comment: Replacing var with prefix_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionValueId generates and MySQL error

Comment: @user3165012 I have updated the code now check that. it will work for you.

Comment: Getting this error from mysql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
      prefix_rsform_submissions
      INNER JOIN prefix_rsform_submission_v' at line 7

Comment: @user3165012 ohk there is remain a comma before the FROM in the query so I have removed that try now.

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias. It says

Comment: @user3165012 you need to add the alias in the table names also it means. I have proposed a query in the edited code. check that. hope that will work for you.

Comment: COOL. Thanks did it, the edited code with alias works :D Your briliant man :)